# How to put multiple documents into Berkeley-DB XML container?

Tags: berkeley-db-xml

I have a directory with a bunch of XML documents and want to put all of them into a container.
In other words, I need to do something like this:

```
dbxml> putDocument tests/*.xml
```

I have written a GUI program to do that but the host server does not have X-windows installed, so must be in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a script that lists files and puts everything into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I do a similar thing when reloading certain XML docs into my current application DB. It helps if all of the files sharing a common naming convention. In python you would could use the following script to add doc001.xml to doc009.xml:

```
from bsddb3.db import *
from dbxml import *

#Load source files 001 - 009

sourceDir = 'C:/directory-containing-xml-docs'
fileRange = range(1,10)

for x in fileRange:
    mycontainer = mymgr.openContainer("myDB.dbxml")    
    xmlucontext = mymgr.createUpdateContext()    
    xmlinput = mymgr.createLocalFileInputStream(sourceDir + "doc00" + str(x) + ".xml")    
    mycontainer.putDocument("doc00" + str(x) + ".xml", xmlinput, xmlucontext)
    print 'Added: ' + str(x)   
    del mycontainer

print '1 - 9 Added'
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could have a shell script write the list of XML files to another file and then call [dbxml_load_container](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17276_01/html/utility/load_container.html) with the -f option.